# event to associate with div

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc

I have an mvc application in which I am getting results from a webservice and assigning it to my model as a property. Now what I want is to pass this result in a javascript function and display some alerts. 
I have the code in javascript but can't find any particular event to associate with my div so that when the page displays, it should trigger that alert (I have tried the div onload). 
The reason I can't attach it to page or any other thing except div is that, it's a partial view with only div's being loaded/unloaded on click of every menu item. Need some help.

**Javascript**

```
myobject.showVerificationStatus = function (verificationStatus) {
        alert("status: " + verificationStatus);
};
```

**View code**

```
@if (Model.HasAnyValue)
{
    var verStatus = Model.ClientVerificationStatus != null ? ((VerificationStatuss)Model.ClientVerificationStatus).ToString().ToUpper() : null;
    <div id="divVerificationStatus" class="divDetail_sectionTitle" onload="object.myObject.showVerificationStatus(@verStatus)"></div>
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `document.ready` on the page. Remove `onload` from `div`. Add your `verStatus` as `data-*` attribute. Consider below example:

**Your viewcode :**

```
@if (Model.HasAnyValue)
{
    var verStatus = Model.ClientVerificationStatus != null ? ((VerificationStatuss)Model.ClientVerificationStatus).ToString().ToUpper() : null;
    <div id="divVerificationStatus" class="divDetail_sectionTitle" data-status="@verStatus"></div>
                                                                 <!--^^^Add this-->
}
```

Now on **document.ready** fetch its `data-status` and `alert` it.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     alert("Status - " + $("#divVerificationStatus").data('status');
});
```

Comment: Probably I can't use document.ready here as the code in my project is something like this:
var object = new function() {
      var object = this;
      object.myObject = new function(){
                var myObject = this;
       myObject.showVerificationStatus = function(verificationStatus){

}
}

}

Comment: Yes I can, have just found document.ready at the start of the View, I'll try your solution and will get back to you, thanks in advance.